# Jsoup always returns null

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to pull data from a HTML String using Jsoup but without success.
The HTML code is

```
<form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Second</th>
        <th>Third</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="elems[][f]" value="one" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="people[][s]" value="two" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="people[][t]" value="three" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="elems[][f]" value="one1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="people[][s]" value="two2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="people[][t]" value="three3" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="next" />
```

I've tried different cases, but nothing. I would retrieve data from th and every td. This is an example for "th":

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(HTMLSTring);

    Elements tables = document.select("table");
    for (Element table : tables){
        Elements ths = table.getElementsByTag("th");
        for(Element th : ths)
        {
            System.out.println(th.text());
        }
    }
```

Comment: No need to check for `tr` first ?

Comment: Have you considered creating a *correct* `<table>`? Where the `<th>` elements are inside `<tr>` elements inside a `<thead>` element? And where the `<td>` elements are grandfathered by a `<tbody>` element?

Comment: You don't need to check for `tr` first because `getElementsByTag` is recursive. Your code works... It's not about JSoup returning `null`. Did you check if you receive the  right  html content in  `HTMLSTring`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works..

If you place your html input into a String variable like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String HTMLSTring= "<form><table><tr><th>First</th><th>Second</th><th>Third</th></tr><tr><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"elems[][f]\" value=\"one\" /></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"people[][s]\" value=\"two\" /></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"people[][t]\" value=\"three\" /></td></tr><tr><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"elems[][f]\" value=\"one1\" /></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"people[][s]\" value=\"two2\" /></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"people[][t]\" value=\"three3\" /></td></tr></table><input type=\"submit\" value=\"next\" />";

    Document document = Jsoup.parse(HTMLSTring);
    Elements tables = document.select("table");
    for (Element table : tables){
        Elements ths = table.getElementsByTag("th");
        for(Element th : ths)
        {
            System.out.println(th.text());
        }
    }
}
```

You will have the expected result.

- First
- Second
- Third

**You may have an issue in the way you are reading the html input.**

Put for example a breakpoint on `Document document = Jsoup.parse(HTMLSTring);` to be sure to receive the righ content.